# Exception: NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azureportal

Can someone please tell me why I get this exception when I test my functional app in Azure Portal? I have all the libraries properly built, and jars are included properly, and I do not get a compiler error. The project builds without any issues.

```
Result: Failure
Exception: NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount
Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount
    at com.example.azureFunctions.Function1.run1(Function1.java:56)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: You understand what the exception name indicates?

Comment: You say you have the library included, but your JVM begs to disagree. What have you included, and how have you done it?

Comment: I had the same problem, but could not resolve it. Is it perhaps anything to do with https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/341